# Problem with .HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, saas

I am using this .htaccess code for my website

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
>   !^www.website.com$ [NC]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
>   ^(www.)?([^.]+).website.com$ [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^$ /application/index.php
>   [L]

This checks for subdomain other than www and displays content from directory `/www/application`

But the problem is for the first time it works correctly and displays the correct page but when i redirect internally/go to other page it loads the content from `/www/` directory and not from `/www/application/` directory.

And it also shows `application` in the url parameter which i want to get rid of.

Ex : url = `http://stackoverflow.website.com/application/user.php`

I want it to be like url = `http://stackoverflow.website.com/user.php` - but from application directory.

Need this for a SAAS Application.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to just setup the subdomain to point directly to that /www/application folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious problem with your rule is that rule is that it will only apply to the root of the domain, because of the `^$` rule. Your probably want to replace that line with something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ application/$1 [L]
```

That will match any URL and divert it to the same URL in your application directory. You might need to add the `QSA` flag to make your app work.

I'd think the problem with "/application/" showing up in your URLs is down to the configuration of the software itself, and how it generates URLs internally. See if it has a config parameter to change its external URL.